# Asterisk jitter buffer on receive side of B-Leg (device side)

Tags: asterisk

I've been trying to apply a jitter buffer to the B-Leg or device side of calls for some time now without any success. I've set the jitter buffer to something very large just to test, using an echo test on a call to *43. My audio is repeated to me instantly which is not what I expect, instead the audio back to me should be delayed by 4000ms.

In sip_general_custom.conf, this setting seems to apply to the receive of the TRUNK, even though that has separate jbenable / jb... settings of just 64 ms fixed jitter buffer. The trunk is not the issue as its fibre from the hosting provider to the trunk.

It's the devices out in the field that are sending auto back over wifi, 3g or satellite (remote phones). I know this configuration only applied to a CHANSIP extension and that's what it's been setup as. Any solution for sip or pjsip is ok.

**sip_general_custom.conf**
jbenable=yes
jblog=yes
jbforce=yes
jbimpl=fixed
jbresyncthreshold=1000
jbmaxsize=4000

Calling from the device: 613 791 8378, 4000 ms delay in the echo test because the jitter buffer is on the receive of a SIP channel, but its from the trunk.

Calling *43 from the device, zero delay in the echo test.